# Why does $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ give vastly different relative errors when $n=252257928$ and $n = 215450934$?

Tags: floating-point

This expression $\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ approximates $e^1$.

- When $n = 252257928$, the relative error, $(e - \text{result})/e$, is $1.740557727387924\mathrm{e-}12$
- When $n = 215450934$, the relative error is $2.430185813419991\mathrm{e-}08$

But both $n$ are very big numbers. Logically, they should produce similar round-off errors, right? But why is that the resulting round-off errors are so different? What's the logic behind it?

I did the Math on Matlab. It looks that Wolfram Alpha produces different round-off errors, but don't know why.

Comment: What is the second $n$?  I think you have a typo in the question

Comment: @MatthewLeingang edited, thanks

Comment: These are quite small numbers, are you mistaking E-08 for E+08?

Comment: @VictoriaM I mean the "N"s are big numbers, not the round-off error. I am wondering why 2 big numbers produce 2 drastically different round-off error

Comment: With Wolfram Alpha, I got errors on the order of $10^{-9}$ for both [$n= 252257928$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1+%2B+(1%2F252257928))%5E252257928-e)%2Fe) and [$n= 215450934$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1+%2B+(1%2F215450934))%5E+215450934-e)%2Fe)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I did it on Matlab.... interesting

Comment: @JoshuaLeung If you could edit the original question to include your code we may be able to tell you where the issue arises, thanks.

Comment: @VictoriaM I added. Thanks!!!

Comment: What precision are the computations using? Given sufficient precision, the relative error should be about $\frac1{2n}$

Comment: @robjohn I am not setting any precision. Maybe the default one?

Comment: @achillehui: $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\lt e$, so the error shouldn't change sign.

Comment: @JoshuaLeung: Using Mathematica, `n = SetPrecision[252257928,16]; (E-(1+1/n)^n)/E` gives `1.982098*10^-9` and `n = SetPrecision[215450934,16]; (E-(1+1/n)^n)/E` gives `2.320714*10^-9`. Both of these match the relative error of $\frac1{2n}$ I mentioned above.

Comment: @robjohn I don't get it. [Matlab also uses 16 digits of precision.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/increase-precision-of-numeric-calculations.html) so it should produce the same number as Mathematica. What did I do wrong......

Comment: @JoshuaLeung: what does the syntax `[err abs(e - result)/abs(e)]` mean in Matlab?

Comment: @robjohn it basically appends the newly calculated relative error abs(e - result)/abs(e) into the array. "err" is the previous values.

Comment: If Mathematica uses a multi-precision data type, then the set precision 16 is the "display" precision. All operations will be executed using an appropriately higher "working" precision, so that ideally the result is exact to the last digit. While the FPU also has an "extended" format that could be used to reduce floating point errors, this effect will only be relevant when the full computation can be kept inside the FPU stack. It is improbable that it will be used that way in an interpreted language.

Comment: @LutzL: I wasn't trying to reproduce the erroneous values; I was just trying to show what the error values *should* be when given sufficient precision. `SetPrecision` only tells Mathematica what the precision, that is $\frac{\text{maximum error}}{\text{value}}$, of a given number is. It will then use arbitrary precision math to give as accurate an answer it can with the given precisions of the numbers given it..

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. It is expected of a true CAS that the results are as accurate as possible, while a numerics software will foremost work with the faster "hard-wired" data types. One could still get the accurate results in double precision by using `exp(n*log1p(1/n))` as alternative expression.

Comment: To see the effect of round-off error, we can simulate a limited precision with `Round`. For example, `n = SetPrecision[252257928,16]; (E-Round[1+1/n,2^-52]^n)/E` gives `-1.741*10^-12` where round-off error is larger than the error of $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, which which would result in a value of `1.982098*10^-9`.

Comment: @JoshuaLeung: you might try `digitsOld=digits(100)` and `n=vpa(252257928)` and `e=exp(vpa(1))` then evaluating things.

Comment: 32 digits should actually be enough, so you could get by without the `digitsOld=digits(100)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result of $1+\frac1n$ is not exactly representable in floating point, you will get an error $\delta$, the value in memory is $1+\frac1n+δ$ with $|δ|\lessapprox\frac{\mu}2$ (rounding to next) where $\mu\approx 2\cdot 10^{-16}$ is the machine constant.

In the final expression this propagates to
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n+δ\right)^n
&=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac1n+δ\right)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(1+nδ-\frac n2\left(\frac1n+δ\right)^2+...\right)\\
&=\exp\left(1+nδ-\frac1{2n}-δ-\frac12nδ^2+...\right)\\
&=e\cdot \left(1+(n-1)δ-\frac1{2n}+...\right)
\end{align}
using $e^{a+b}=e^a(1+b+\frac12b^2+...)$ if $|b|\ll 1$.
The leading terms in the relative error are $(n-1)δ$ and $-\frac1{2n}$. The first, random term will reach in its bound the size of the second, theoretical error at around $n\simeq \sqrt{\frac1{\mu}}$ which is about $10^8$. For larger $n$ the random floating point error of maximum size $n\frac{\mu}2$ dominates.

Around $n=10^8$ where both influences balance, it can happen by chance that they are really of equal size but opposing sign, that is, that $δ\approx-\frac1{2n^2}$, so that the resulting error is much smaller than the bounds predict.

- For the given example $n=252257928$ in the question one gets $2^{52}(\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2})=17853153.999968924$, and thus a very small combined error around $n\cdot 3⋅10^{-5}⋅\mu=1.5⋅10^{-12}$.
- For the "normal" case example $n=215450934$ this mantissa computation leads to $\frac{2^{52}}n=20903133.459474795$ and thus rounding down by about $δ=-0.5⋅\mu<0$, so that the errors $-0.5/n=-2.32⋅10^{-9}$ and $-0.5⋅\mu⋅(n+1)=-2.39⋅10^{-8}$ reinforce each other.

[image: plot of the relative error]

Comment: I am sorry... how did you get the leading error terms (−1)δ and −1/2??? I have been looking at the answer for a very long time and still can't get my head around it.

Comment: Also, why did you divide machine epsilon by 2? |δ| ≤ /2, where is this coming from?

Comment: The leading error terms (relative error) should now be more explicit. In $[1,2]$ the distance between consecutive floating point numbers is $\mu$. Thus the distance from any real number in $[1,2]$ to the next floating point number is half of that, $\mu/2$.